# Exporting a data from database to .txt or .csv file by using UTL_file package in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a directory in postgres just like oracle for example(CREATE or replace DIRECTORY test_dir AS 'c:\test').I'm unable to create it.
for example

```
CREATE or replace DIRECTORY test_dir AS 'c:\test'

 DECLARE
  vf  UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  VNM VARCHAR(20);
BEGIN
  SELECT ENAME
  INTO   VNM
  FROM   EMP
  WHERE  EMPNO = 7839;

  vf := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('TEST_DIR', 'names.txt', 'A');

  UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(vf, 'TEST DATA');
  UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(vf, VNM);

  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(vf);

END;
/
```

I wanted to write a data into flat file like .txt or.csv from database.
Can you please help me how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The above example is of Oracle utl_file package.

Comment: Sounds like the XY-problem... Why eat soup with a fork? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: @joop, Can u give me one example for utl_file package in postgresql. I googled it but not found.Thank you.

Comment: There is no `utl_file` package in Postgres. And there is no equivalent thing as `create directory` in Postgres either. If you want to export data into a flat file, just use the `COPY` command: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I wanted to select some fields by using joins and I need to put that in .csv or .txt file. Thank you.

Comment: Repeat: Use COPY. And read the manual how to use it. COPY does accept a SELECT statement, no matter how many joins you use.

Comment: You can put any subquery you want into a copy statement `COPY(SELECT ... FROM a JOIN b ON a.x=b.y) TO '/tmp/ab.tsv';`

Comment: Oh yes,  Finally got it. Thank you everyone.